# Convert DbSet<T1> to DbSet<T2> where T1 and T2 have same signature

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this code:

```
public DbSet<TDestination> Table
{
    get { return Db.TSource; }
}
```

How do I convert `DbSet<TSource>` to `DbSet<TDestination>`?

Comment: `return db.Set<TSource>()`

Comment: A [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help.

Comment: What does "T1 and T2 have same signature" mean?  Two objects may look alike, but that doesn't mean you can cast one to the other.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Can a generic repository help, where that generic parameter is constrained to an interface containing the members that are shared between T1 and T2, so you can do `Repository<T>.Find(e => e.SomeSharedProperty == "42")`?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a converter that is doing exactly what you want and can be reused wherever you want.  I did an answer here on it that is self extracting: [Expression-tree to build sub-select results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375510/expression-tree-to-build-sub-select-results/43376576#43376576)

Or going off the values in my example you can just do it inline too:

```
ChildPOC poc = new ChildPOC(1, "Brett", "X");
var alterPocOnDemand = new ChildPOCAlter(poc.FirstName, poc.LastName, poc.ParentId);
```

I would leave EF Db Sets alone though and provide a level after them.  Unless you are going to change EF's T4 template(the *.tt file in your project) you are playing with fire trying to cast objects of DBSet to DBSet.  Generally those are queryable objects meant to act a certain way by EF and not fully realized objects.  They are tightly wound to EF and as such it would be far better to do something like this:

```
List<X> realItems = new List<X>();
using(var context = new YourContext())
{
   realItems = context.Table.Where(x => x.Thing == "some predicate").ToList();
}
```

When you play with DbSet that is close to the level of EF and is in a more attached method to the database versus a List, IEnumerable, or other container object is fully realized and able to be reused more easily.

Comment: A `DbSet<T>` talks to the database. Converting sounds like you're going to convert all records from `T1` to `T2` just to be able to access them in the same way, which sounds suboptimal to say the least. Can you show an example in this answer, and explain how it helps the asker?

Comment: I amended my answer, I would not convert one DbSet<X> to DbSet<Y> for reasons you said of database access.  What do you find suboptimal about Converters and selecting into new objects?  As opposed to what exactly?  Generally I do converters for a repository pattern in WPF where I am taking ADO.NET or EF objects that have a small light weight object with just a POCO and then to a more formalized object that has INotifyProperty Changed implemented and is serializable by use with a converter.

Comment: Yes, of course you convert from a domain model to a view model and vice versa. I meant when querying on collection A, that happens to look like collection B, you don't go and pull all records of table A, convert them to B and execute the query in-memory as if A is-a B. The latter is what it appeared like you were suggesting. There are better solutions available, but their feasibility depends on what exactly the OP is trying to do, which is unclear to me.